# Webcam not found every other day (Chromium reboots)

Tags: 16.04, usb, chromium, webcam, logitech

I am using an USB Logitech HD Pro Webcam C920 for some software I am using to collect pictures or products in a factory. This computer doesn't reboot at night (confirmed with uptime) but every morning I get a "Device not found" error both in my software and in Cheese Webcam Booth and I need to unplug and re-plug my device to have it detected for the day.

Is there anything I should do to have it work for good?

Comment: Do you have the computer set to sleep? Do you find that this occurs after wake from sleep? Any why do you reboot every morning?

Comment: @heynnema My "Suspend when inactive" setting is at "Don't suspend" and I do not reboot every morning.